# How to access my custom python scripts from CLI in order for them to act on any file?

Tags: python

I am having difficulty accessing my custom scripts from the command line (`python3 unzipit.py "C:\Users\Me\downloads\zipfilehome"`). I want to have my scripts act on any file, no matter where they are. I don't want to have the script file in the same directory in order for it to work. I followed this question's [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/2986242) to no avail. Note: I am using Windows 10 and all my python versions are in the path with no issues accessing them.

#### What I did (I always refresh my CLI with every change)

In the system environmental variables:

```
Path: (unchanged since installation) C:\Path2Python27;C:\Path2Python27\scripts;C:\Path2Python37;C:\Path2Python37\scripts;

PYTHONPATH: C:\Path2Python37;C:\Path2Python37\scripts;C:\Users\Me\myscripts\py
```

#### Things I also tried

- system environmental variables

`Path: C:\Path2Python27;C:\Path2Python27\scripts;C:\Path2Python37;C:\Path2Python37\scripts;C:\Users\Me\myscripts\py`

- moving the same stuff to user env's `Path`
- moving the above-shown system `PYTHONPATH` to the user env

What else am I missing? I don't understand.

---

All in all, what I needed to get this working:

system environmental variables

```
Path: C:\Path2Python27;C:\Path2Python27\scripts;C:\Path2Python37;C:\Path2Python37\scripts;

PYTHONPATH: C:\Users\Me\myscripts\py
```

and

making sure to use [Andriy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56933885/2986242). It won't work using `python3 unzipit.py "C:\link\to\folder"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want you have to specify `-m` flag and the module name, so python will retrieve module by looking up python module path. See more here in [interface-options](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#interface-options). The command shall be:

```
python3 -m unzipit "C:\Users\Me\downloads\zipfilehome"
```

Comment: I tried that and got `C:\Path2Python37\python3.exe: Error while finding module specification for 'unzipit.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: __path__ attribute not found on 'unzipit' while trying to find 'unzipit.py')`.

Comment: Oh, I was supposed to remove the `.py` extension.